# How do to identify that a file is a package?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsfilemanager

I have used NSDirectoryEnumerator to enumerate files in a Cocoa App (OSX). I am able to identify many properties of files e.g that a file is a directory or not, its creation date,modification date etc using NSURL File Property Keys. What I am not able to identify is that whether a file is a package or not ? I have gone through every bit of NSURL,NSFileManager reference but I have not been able to find a way. Am I missing something ?

I have also seen that for a file that is a package NSURLIsDirectoryKey returns true. But in my case I still want to categorise directories and packages separately.

Comment: Do you mean "bundle"?

Comment: No ! I am just traversing a directory in OSX App and what I need is to distinguish between directories and packages. I want to know that a file enumerated is a package or not.

Comment: @Kevin I had that solution before posting this question that why not if NSURLIsDirectoryKey returns true check that whether the file has an extension like .something then that means its a package but what about folders named in mac like com.something.something etc ?

Comment: NSWorkspace provides a [high level interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/isFilePackageAtPath:) for that kind of thing.  LaunchServices provides the low level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the method in NSWorkspace class. wonder why it was not included in NSURL File Property Keys

```
- (BOOL)isFilePackageAtPath:(NSString *)fullPath
```

> Return Value
>   YES if the path identifies a file package; otherwise, NO if the path does not exist, is not a directory, or is not a file package.